# Bootstrap 4.1.1 nav bar toggler not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

been trying to solve this for some time now, the nav bar toggler button icon is not appearing on my page at all.I believe all of the necessary files are setup corectly and all is loading fine on dev inspect, no errors on console as well.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>##########</title>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--============Navigation================-->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <img src="img/####### logo 2.png" class="navbar-brand">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"  aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Product</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `popper.min.js`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img src="img/####### logo 2.png" class="navbar-brand">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" style="background-color: green;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"  aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Product</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```